# This program only allow me to enter once, why?

Tags: c, scanf

```
 char a;
 char b;

printf("Enter a charater: ");
scanf("%c", &a);
printf("Your input is: %c\n", a);
printf("The address of this charater is: %u\n", &a);

printf("Enter a charater: ");
scanf("%c", &b);
printf("Your input is: %c\n", b);
printf("The address of this charater is: %u\n", &b);
```

I can only input the first one, it skips the second input, why???

Comment: That said, use `%p` for printing pointers.

Comment: ... which you must manually cast to `void*` when you pass them as arguments

Comment: Probably `b` is loaded with LF (new line) code. You enter e.g. `Y`, hit enter - first `scanf` gets `Y`, second - LF (new line/enter). Add 2-3 additional `scanf`-s.